# How do I install/uninstall GRUB to change the primary boot manager owner?

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, dual-boot, uefi, boot-loader

I have a dual boot system with 2 versions (derivatives) of Ubuntu installed (Linux Mint 17.3 KDE and Kubuntu 18.04).

In order to keep the LM install in control of the GRUB boot manager updates (because it is my primary OS), I installed Kubuntu telling it not to install the boot manager (using `ubiquity -b`, which I found in Rod Smith's answer to [How to keep grub independent of all the OSes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705063/how-to-keep-grub-independent-of-all-the-oses))

This is working fine. I have to manually run `update-grub` from LM after installing a new kernel in Kubuntu in order for it to be on the boot menu.

I'm at the point where I need to switch control of the grub boot manager from the 1st OS (LM) to the 2nd (Kubuntu).

So what I'd like to do is install grub on the 2nd OS (Kubuntu 18.04) so that it updates the grub boot manager on the ESP (efi system partition) and then uninstall grub from the 1st OS so that it no longer updates the grub boot manager on the ESP.

I'd like not to have to wipe my 2nd OS partition and re-install it from scratch.

Comment: Grub, as boot manager, whose job is boot the OS, if it relies on the existence of the OS, how can it work? So, grub is not related to any OS. Then what's the `update-grub` command `grub-install` used to install the grub?  They're the grub package (or whatever your OS name it), providing the management tools for the OS to manage grub.

Comment: In addition to what @炸鱼薯条德里克 said: you can basically use the grub tools from any modern os to manage grub. So technically, you can update it from LM and Kubuntu (as long as you have to grub package installed). `update-grub` mostly compiles and stores a text file which tells grub where to look for the kernel (simplified explaination).

Comment: @rudib I know that's not quite the case, and not quite what I'm trying to learn. Because the grub version installed on my 2 OS's might be different, when I installed Kubuntu, I used the `-b` switch to tell it not to install grub, what I think this means is that the grub configuration used on boot is _always_ the one created by running `update-grub` on LM the one created by running `update-grub` on Kubuntu is ignored.

Comment: I can't find any documentation on a `-b` switch for `ubiquity` (according to the [ubuntu manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/ubiquity.8.html)). But if there is a `-b` switch, it might tell it not to run `grub-install`. `grub-install` is usually run by the setup tool, but you didn't need that as it was already installed and set up by LM. `update-grub` is just a stub for `grub(2)-mkconfig`. Those config files should be compatible and interchangeable. In addition to that, you could check `/etc/grub.d` on both OSs and match Kubuntu to LM. Then the output of `grub-mkconfig` %

Comment: should be identical.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/465189/update-grub-vs-grub-install

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't find any doc for `-b` either other than that in Rod Smith's answer. I have also noticed a difference in the grub packages installed on the 2 OS's, so if I want/need to run `grub-install` from Kubuntu, I suspect I need to install missing grub packages, i just have to figure out which ones.

Comment: There may be a switch we don't know of, but it may be possible that you actually installed **grub bootloader** (`grub-install`) again during the Kubuntu install and didn't notice it. Do you have the **grub package** installed on Kubuntu?

Comment: That stackexchange link was super helpful in pointing me where to look next. I had just looked at `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg` which I can see loads the grub config from my LM partition.

Comment: `grub-common`, `grub2-common`, `grub-pc` and `grub-pc-bin` are the only grub packages I see installed on Kubuntu. I wonder what running `grub-install` would do w/o the grub efi packages, but I'm not sure I want to experiment w/ something that might break my system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99238/discussion-between-mike-lippert-and-rudib).

Answer (score 0):

The Kubuntu install with `ubuquity -b` installed legacy grub packages:

- grub-pc
- grub-pc-bin
- grub-gfxpayload-lists

Uninstall those packages then install the grub efi packages for your system, e.g. for my 64bit x86:

- grub-efi-amd64
- grub-efi-amd64-bin
- grub-efi-amd64-signed

The installation of these packages runs `grub-install` and updates the files in `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu` namely the `grub.cfg` and `grubx64.efi`.

I suspect that uninstalling these grub efi packages on the Linux Mint boot would work so that it could still run `update-grub` when updating the kernel but no updates to grub that re-run `grub-install` would happen. However I have not tested this.